# Export Drupal Commerce Checkout Settings

Tags: 7, commerce, features, importing-exporting

I'm wondering if there's a way to export Drupal Commerce's checkout pane settings to code?  I've tried commerce_features but it doesn't appear to do it.

For other commerce related things, like payment rules, I've been able to export them using features and using hook_default_default_rules_configuration_alter to make sure only the proper rules are in place.

However for checkout I've not been able to find anything.

Answer (score 3):

The checkout configuration is all managed via standard Drupal variables, so the Strongarm module with Features is all you should need. All variables in our modules will be prefixed with commerce_* and typically with the module name (e.g. commerce_checkout_*).

Comment: commerce_checkout_completion message is the only one I see.  The order and settings of the individual panes doesn't seem to be there.  I wonder if it's because I have some 3rd party modules messing things up?

Comment: Yeah, I interpreted settings as the configuration of individual checkout pane features. The positioning of the panes themselves on pages is governed by data in the commerce_checkout_pane table, which would require some Features integration or something else to export.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: It does not seem to be correct. `commerce_checkout_pane_save()` writes to the database table `commerce_checkout_pane`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Commerce Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_migrate) module?

> Commerce Migrate is a general-purpose migration framework extending
>   Migrate Module for bringing store information into Drupal Commerce.
>
> - Migrate destination field handlers for commerce fields (reference fields, price field)
> - Migrate destination plugin for commerce product types.

Comment: From what I can tell that's for migrating products and product settings, not really for checkout/payment.  And I'm not migrating from one site to a new one, it's for a dev/stage/production workflow so we can export configuration to code and revert it when need be.

Comment: there is a new release and much documentation on migrate that it should be fairly easy to implement your specific request.. Im simply directing you to the most simple form of doing your project.....

Answer (score 0):

Commerce features has now support for this since a few months...
https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_features

See the related issue at: https://www.drupal.org/node/1973602